# Should we create a separate identify-this-short tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Looking around the [identify-this-movie](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-movie) tag, I spotted we have [at least **50**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/search?q=[identify-this-movie]%20short%20is%3Aquestion) questions in the tag which are specifically asking for a short film, rather than a feature length movie.

Does this qualify it as deserving its own tag at this point? The numbers will certainly increase quickly judging by how many `identify-this-x` questions we get daily and if they were converted over, [identify-this-short](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-short) would be the 25th most popular tag on the site.

Comment: Well, at least taking some weight from `identify-this-movie` could defer the day when it becomes the most used tag of the site. And as inevitable as this day might be I don't want to imagine it. ;-)

Comment: Noooooo.....no more IDish tag. Anyways short film are films. so no more tag requirement needed here.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure such a distinction is really necessary, since short movies are in fact movies like any other movie, too. We in turn have a [short-films](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/short-films) tag that can be added to [identify-this-movie](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-movie) questions, in the same way like decade or genre tags. While this of course requires effort from the asker to add that tag, this would be the same effort required to tag a question [identify-this-short](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-short) instead of [identify-this-movie](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-movie), and ID questions often need proper retagging anyway.

Likewise am I not sure if the [identify-this-short](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-short) tag might encourage ID questions about any kind of short, like YouTube clips or whatever questionable media.

Answer (score -3):

I do not have a problem with this .... but it will require some effort to re-tag.